# SharePoint 2010 web service - GetListItems not working in Chrome & firefox

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
    function GetListItems() {

        var soapEnv = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
             "<soap:Body> " +
             "<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> " +
              "<listName>SomeList</listName> " +
               "<query><Query><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>1</Value></Gt></Where></Query></query> " +
              " <viewFields> <ViewFields> <FieldRef Name='SomeContent' /></ViewFields></viewFields> " +
              "<rowLimit>100</rowLimit>" +
             "<queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' ><QueryOptions/> " +
            "</queryOptions> </GetListItems></soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";


        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://sharepointsiteurl/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",

            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            error: ErrorFunc,
            complete:GetListItemsComplete,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    }
    function ErrorFunc(xData, status) {
        debugger;
        alert(xData.responseText);
    }
    function GetListItemsComplete(xData, status) {

        var a = xData.responseText;
        alert(a);
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr("ows_SomeContent");
            $($(this).attr("ows_SomeContent")).appendTo("#Announcements");
        });

    }

</script>
<a href="#" onclick="Javascript:GetListItems();">Get List Items</a>
<div id="Announcements">
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What do you mean not working? Do you receive an error? Or is the information just not displayed in your element?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Newer versions of it have made using the find("z\\:row") obsolete so to speak. Have you tried to use the SPServices jQuery library? It is really good at stuff like that.

Comment: Not working in the sense the output of listitems is not fetched in chrome and firefox....only a empty alert window.Add i get an status:parsererror during debugging in chrome.

Comment: Not enough information...

Comment: Its working fine in IE i.e,if i click on Get List Items i will get the listitems but in chrome and firefox its not working

Comment: In chrome when i debug using F!0, i will get an soapEnv: undefined error in  function GetListItems()and parse error in  function ErrorFunc(xData, status)

Comment: I am using jquery/1.4.2/ version it works fine in IE but not in chrome and firefox

Comment: Try using type as 'GET' or empty.

Comment: Why are you retrieving $(this).attr("ows_SomeContent") twice, instead of just using your title attribute the second time?

Comment: If i add once also its not working in chrome and firefox
And let me know if i need to modify the code

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of advice given here, but your real problem is with parsing the XML that has been returned from you.  The problem is with this call: `$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row")`.  That is no longer supported AT ALL with jQuery 1.5+ in a cross browser way. You say you are using 1.4.2, but I strongly suggest you verify the version you are using by typing `jQuery.fn.jquery` in your console.  This will tell you the version number that is loaded in the browser.  Keep in mind there may be multiple versions over jQuery loaded...

For those that like to read up on the bugs...

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8120

This 'bug' introduced a lot of confusion with existing code.  Quite honestly because a lot of developers didn't take the time to read the documentation.  To solve your problem, you'll have to parse your XML a different way.  The preferred method is with this function:

```
$.fn.SPFilterNode = function(name) {
   return this.find('*').filter(function() {
       return this.nodeName === name;
  });
};
```

Just add this function to your existing script prior to your Web Service calls and use it like this:

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
   var title = $(this).attr("ows_SomeContent");
   $($(this).attr("ows_SomeContent")).appendTo("#Announcements");
});
```

[Note: part of the above content was copied/ taken from Steve Workman's blog - see link [here](http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2011/improving-javascript-xml-node-finding-performance-by-2000/)]

And I'd be amiss if I didn't send you to the king of all king's for SharePoint Web Services:

http://sympmarc.com/2011/11/08/problem-with-jquery-1-7-and-spservices/

With all this said, you really ought to be using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) for all of your front-end activities.  There are different API's available in 2010, but since you are asking about the Web Services specifically, this is the de facto standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Http Debugging issue Fiddler / Network Monitor tool.

http://www.cantoni.org/2010/08/19/fiddler-any-browser

http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp

You can compare the Fiddler / Network Monitor traces of IE & Firefox and Chrome & Firefox. This would give you a clear idea on how to fix this issue

Reference:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/cfacbd54-f08c-4671-a6e7-a083965542e2

Comment: I tried using Get or empty type but its not working.And dont know how to use a Fiddler

Comment: I tried using Fiddler..but didnt work

Comment: Getting an 200 ok status error

Comment: im still facing with the same problem....PLz anyone help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I use this with IE, FF, and Chrome. You need to add the headers object to your $.ajax() request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://sharepointsiteurl/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    headers: {
        "SOAPAction": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems",
        "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    },
    success: function (xmlDoc, status, res) {
        var readyState = res.readyState; //4
        var responseXML = res.responseXML; //XML as Document
        var responseText = res.responseText; //XML as string
        var status = res.status; //200
        var statusText = res.statusText; //'OK'

        /* 
           A simple workaround with RegEx to replace z:row with zrow for browsers 
           that don't implement document.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'z:row') or
           won't read z:row with getElementsByTagName, namely IE.
           SPServices is great but you don't need it if you want a leaner app.
           without unnecessary dependencies that can break your page in later versions
           of either jQuery or SPServices.
        */
        var temp = document.createElement('div');
        temp.innerHTML = responseText.replace(/z:row/g, 'zrow');
        var rows = temp.getElementsByTagName('zrow');

        //process the rows...
    },
    error: function (xmlDoc, status, res) {
        //handle
    }
});
```